# NSNumberFormatter positiveFormat

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I need to format decimal numbers using NSNumberFormatter. 
The result needs to be as follow

7 => 7

7.1 => 7.10

so if number have decimal part show it with 2 decimals.

I've tried with maximumFractionDigits = 2 and positiveFormat = @"###0.00" but it's not giving result I'm expecting

7 => 7.00

7.1 => 7.10

What is best positiveFormat to achieve my result?

here is code I'm using

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = @"###0.00";
```

**My solution**

```
if ([number doubleValue] == [number integerValue]) {
    // use formatter with minimumFractionDigits = 0 and maximumFractionDigits = 0
} else {
    // use formatter with minimumFractionDigits = 2 and maximumFractionDigits = 2
}
```

Comment: did you try my answer? it's pretty straightforward, if works, consider accepting it.

Comment: Your own solution is great

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve that by setting properties of `NSNumberFormatter`. You can achieve that in two ways:

First way:

subclass `NSNumberFormatter` and implement it's `stringFromNumber:` method (or any related that you use for formatting. Then you set manually both `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` before formatting, like this (pseudocode) in `stringFromNumber` override, "numberHasDecimalFraction" is boolean condition you have to implement:

```
if(numberHasDecimalFraction){
    self.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
    self.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
}else{
    self.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
    self.maximumFractionDigits = 0;
}

return [super stringFromNumber: number];
```

Second way:

Create a wrapper around two formatters and use it to format falling back on one of them depending on condition of having fraction digits similar to what you have in first way.